# How is this class object implemented?

Tags: c++, class, oop, abstract-class

The following is an incomplete code from hackerrank-

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class AdvancedArithmetic{
    public:
        virtual int divisorSum(int n)=0;
};
class Calculator : public AdvancedArithmetic {
public:
    int divisorSum(int n) {
        return 0;
    }
};

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    AdvancedArithmetic *myCalculator = new Calculator(); 
    int sum = myCalculator->divisorSum(n);
    cout << "I implemented: AdvancedArithmetic\n" << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

How does the line
`AdvancedArithmetic *myCalculator = new Calculator();` correct?
Like how does this work? Creating *mycalculator object of an interface and initializing with Calculator?
If Calculator had a few more functions which wasn't in the interface, then how would calling those functions work?

Comment: You probably need to learn about inheritance and polymorphism first.

Comment: The code is leaking memory as well.

Comment: Not just memory. It also does not call a destructor. Which, by the way, needs to be `virtual` to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: I mentioned it that the code is incomplete. It was a hackerrank problem so I didn't wanted to write the whole code because I just had that question.